# catch similar words in a line

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I've the below string.

```
What is (Jim)'s gift (limit)? <=> Personname <=> Amount::Spent
```

in this line I want to find and print the start and end positions of `(` and `)`.

In my current code, I'm able to print it, but the problem is, it is getting printed multiple times (I'm sure that this is because of the `while`).

My code is as below.

```
    String line = "What is (Rakesh)'s gift (limit)? <=> Personname <=> Amount::Spent";
    if (line.contains("<=>")) {
        String[] example_split = line.split("<=>", 2);
        System.out.println("String is " + example_split[1]);
        if (example_split[0].length() > 1) {
            String[] example_entity = example_split[1].split("<=>");

            for (String splitStrings : example_entity) {
                int openParamCount = line.length() - line.replace("(", "").length();
                int closeParamCount = line.length() - line.replace("(", "").length();
                System.out.println(openParamCount + "\t" + closeParamCount);
                if (!(openParamCount == closeParamCount))
                    System.out.println("Paranthesis don't match for " + line);
                if (!(openParamCount == example_entity.length))
                    System.out.println(
                            "The entities provided and the words marked in paranthesis don't match for " + line);

                int entities_count = 0;
                int no_of_entities = example_entity.length;
                Set utterancesSet = new HashSet<>();
                int startPosition = 0;
                int endPosition = 0;
                while (entities_count < no_of_entities) {
                    List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
                    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
                    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
                        startPosition = regexMatcher.start() + 1;
                        endPosition = regexMatcher.start() - 1;

                        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
                        System.out.println("start position is " + startPosition + " end position is " + endPosition
                                + " Entity Type" + example_entity[entities_count]);
                    }
                    entities_count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected output:

```
String is  Personname <=> Amount::Spent
2   2
start position is 9 end position is 12 Entity Type Personname 
start position is 22 end position is 27 Entity Type Amount::Spent
```

Current output

```
String is  Personname <=> Amount::Spent
2   2
start position is 9 end position is 12 Entity Type Personname 
start position is 22 end position is 27 Entity Type Personname 
start position is 9 end position is 12 Entity Type Amount::Spent
start position is 22 end position is 27 Entity Type Amount::Spent
2   2
start position is 9 end position is 12 Entity Type Personname 
start position is 22 end position is 27 Entity Type Personname 
start position is 9 end position is 12 Entity Type Amount::Spent
start position is 22 end position is 27 Entity Type Amount::Spent
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove 2 loops

1. The "for (String splitStrings : example_entity) "
2. The "while (entities_count < no_of_entities) "

```
    String line = "What is (Rakesh)'s gift (limit)? <=> Personname <=> Amount::Spent";
    if (line.contains("<=>")) {
        String[] example_split = line.split("<=>", 2);
        System.out.println("String is " + example_split[1]);
        if (example_split[0].length() > 1) {
            String[] example_entity = example_split[1].split("<=>");

            int openParamCount = line.length() - line.replace("(", "").length();
            int closeParamCount = line.length() - line.replace("(", "").length();
            System.out.println(openParamCount + "\t" + closeParamCount);
            if (!(openParamCount == closeParamCount))
                System.out.println("Paranthesis don't match for " + line);
            if (!(openParamCount == example_entity.length))
                System.out.println(
                        "The entities provided and the words marked in paranthesis don't match for " + line);

            int entities_count = 0;
            int startPosition;
            int endPosition = 0;
            List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<>();
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
            Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
            while (regexMatcher.find()) {
                startPosition = regexMatcher.start() + 1;
                endPosition = regexMatcher.start() - 1;

                matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
                System.out.println("start position is " + startPosition + " end position is " + endPosition
                        + " Entity Type" + example_entity[entities_count]);
            }
            entities_count++;
        }
    }
```

Your code though suggests that the parenthesis will always be closing and it does not allow room for inner loops for example

> What is ((jim)'s and (kyle)'s) gift (limit)?

Does not return the correct result. But this is only a problem if you would expect input in that form.